# can a relationship in core data link an instance of an entity twice to another instance

Tags: ios, core-data

I want to make a to-many relationship that can save an instance of an entity more than ones.

for exemple, lets say I have two entities: buyer, product.
now I have a buyer "jon", and a product "tomato", jon should be able to have more then 1 tomato.

another solution may be to save a counter somewhere, but i cant find an efficient way to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways to do that, depending on your needs:

- Create a different object for each individual tomato, so that you're modeling every tomato anyone ever purchases. This probably isn't a great strategy for tomatoes, where you don't care much about the individual objects, but it could be a good plan for cars, where each vehicle is unique and should be tracked separately.
- Create an entity that represents a purchase transaction. Jon isn't buying the same tomato several times, he's buying *some* tomato several times. The thing you want to track isn't the tomato but the purchase.

Comment: I don't understand, how will you implement the second solution?

Comment: @litov add an entity called Purchase to your data model. Give it a relationship to Person called 'purchaser', a to-many relationship to the things that are purchased, and maybe date and other relevant attributes. The buyer would then have a to-many relationship to purchases instead of products.